# Entity Framework - Users and Groups with Many to Many tables

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I have run into an issue that has me going around in circles.  What I need to implement is users and groups in our website.  We are using Entity Framework (database first) with ASP.NET in C#.

Here are the requirements:

1. There are users
2. There are groups (which are created by the administrator and will exist in the DB)
3. Each users can be in one or more groups
4. Each group can have 0 or more users.

The current Groups are:
Administrator
Board of Directors
Editors

So in short, "User1" can be in both the Editor & Board of Directors groups but not a member of the Administrator group.

First I constructed my database with a Users, a Groups and a UserGroups table.  The userGroups table has the following fields:

> ```
> User              Group
> -----------       ------------
> UserId (PK)       GroupId (PK)
> Name              Name
> ...               ...
>
>        \           /
>           UserGroup
>          -------------
>           UserGroupTestID (PK)
>           UserId (FK)
>           GroupId (FK)
> ```

The problem with this approach is that EF will not let me add more than 1 user to this table throwing a "Multiplicity constraint violated" error since it was a 1 User to Many relationship.

So I changed it to be a many-to-many table by dropping the PK as follows:

```
User              Group
-----------       ------------
UserId (PK)       GroupId (PK)
Name              Name
...               ...

       \           /
          UserGroup
         -------------
          UserId (FK)
          GroupId (FK)
```

I was now able to access user.Group and was able to add a group to this user.  When I was adding a user to a group, I was querying the existing groups and adding it like this:

user.Groups.Add( ctx.Groups.Where( g => g.GroupID == 12 ).First( );

The problem is that this created a new group for this user in the Groups table - even though the ID of the Group was correct (12) when it was saved to the database.

I need to do the following things:

1. Create a user and put the new user in 1 or more groups.
2. Edit an existing user to add or remove them from groups.

I am sure that I am doing something wrong (and probably bone-headed), but if anyone can help me to achieve this, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

Code in Admin_AddUser.aspx.cs:

```
User user = new User( );
user.CustomerID = CustomerID;
user.IsClub = false;
user.IsDistrict = true;
user.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
user.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
user.Email = txtEmail.Text;
user.Password = txtPassword.Text;
user.AccountActive = true;

foreach( RadListBoxItem item in lbSelectedRoles.Items )
{
  user.Roles.Add( UserData.GetRole( DCManager.Instance.SiteSettings.Customer.CustomerID, int.Parse( item.Value ) ) );
}

bool rtn = UserData.CreateUser( user );
...
```

Code in CreateUser method:

```
public static bool CreateUser( User user )
{
  using ( var ctx = new DCEntities( ) )
  {
    //Check if the login credentials already exist
    if ( ctx.Users.Where( u => u.Email == user.Email
                           && u.Password == user.Password ).Count( ) > 0 )
      return false;
    else
    {
      ctx.Users.Add( user );
      ctx.SaveChanges( );

      return true;
    }
  }
}
```

=========================

In my project, the Groups and actually called "Roles"

Since the UserGroups table in the DB is a many-to-many, it is not show in the EDMX file, but the Users & Groups (Roles in my db) are linked as many-to-many.
[image: Objects]

Mapping Details:

[image: User Mapping Details]
[image: Roles Mapping Details]

Comment: Could you post your mappings?

Comment: Hi mmillican - I'm not sure what you mean by mappings.  Do you mean from the SQL or EF EDMX side?

Comment: If you're not using code first, the EDMX.

Comment: OK - do you want it from the Mapping Details window and for which objects?  Both Users & Groups?

Comment: Yes, that should work, for both.

Comment: I hope that is what you were looking for!

Comment: An image of the class model would be more useful. It's not clear to me whether the `UserGroup` entity is part of the class model.

Comment: I have added an image of the EDMX objects showing the User & Groups objects relationship to each other (many-to-many)

Comment: So it's a pure many to many association. Still it's a problem that you hardly show any code. A description, however detailed, doesn't make up for that. I don't know where the `user` comes from. Is it attached to `ctx`? I *think* you mark the user as `Added` after assigning the group, so the group is marked as `Added` as well.

Comment: Hi Gert - I have added the code that creates the new User object (in the ASPX.CS file) and saves it (CreateUser method) where the issue happens that a new role is added.

Comment: So there it is, you should attach the roles to `ctx` before `ctx.Users.Add( user )`.

Comment: Hi Gert - I am not sure I follow...  I have always just added the entry in the UserGroup table manually (created new entried by looping through the objects), but I would like to have EF do it so it is done properly.  Could you provide me with some sample code of what you mean?  Thanks again in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly. I would recommend you do the following:

1. Create a table UsersAndGroups (int: PK, UserId: FK, GroupId: FK).
2. Establish relationships between Users and UsersAndGroups as one-to-many.
3. Establish relationships between Groups and UsersAndGroups as one-to-many.
4. Remove relationship between Users and Groups.

This will allow you the following:

1. Add User to one or more groups by adding rows to UsersAndGroups table.
2. Get User groups by selecting all records with certain UserId from UsersAndGroups table.
3. Get Group users by selecting all records with certain GroupId from UsersAndGroups table.

Hope I understood you right.

Comment: Hi Aleh - I think you understood me right.  I did that initially (created 3 tables) but EF had the User & Group side of the relationships as one to many.  Are you suggesting I create 5 tables in total?  Add 2 more "bridge" tables to create the many to many relation ship between the UsersAndGroups & Users and UsersAndGroups & Groups?

Comment: Hi Nutkraker, my bad. The relationships should be one-to-many from User to UsersAndGroups and from Group to UsersAndGroups (edited).

Comment: Hi Aleh - the problem with that is that the User can only be part of 1 group in that case where I need them to be able to be in more than 1 group.

Comment: Hi Nutkraker - the user can be a member of any number of groups. Each record in UsersAndGroups table defines the relationship between User and Group. The User and Group tables are not related to each other directly. So to add User to a group you should simply add one more record to the UsersAndGroups table.

Answer (score 0):

Using code first:

To Roles add

```
public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }
```

To Users add

```
public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Your classes might look like this

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;


namespace MyProject.EFTest
{
    public class Role
    {
        [Key]
        public int RoleID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<User> Users { get; set; }

    }

    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserID { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual List<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    }

}
```

When the migration is generated EF will create table UserRole in addition to Users and Roles

```
    CreateTable(
        "dbo.UserRole",
        c => new
            {
                User_UserID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                Role_RoleID = c.Int(nullable: false),
            })
        .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.User_UserID, t.Role_RoleID })
        .ForeignKey("dbo.User", t => t.User_UserID)
        .ForeignKey("dbo.Role", t => t.Role_RoleID)
        .Index(t => t.User_UserID)
        .Index(t => t.Role_RoleID);
```